# Open NSMenu from NSButton with storyboard

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsmenu

Without storyboard this code works perfectly. It opens NSMenu

```
-(IBAction)openExportCompletePaletteMenu:(id)sender {    
NSPoint point = [self.window convertRectToScreen:((NSButton*)sender).frame].origin;
[self.menu popUpMenuPositioningItem:nil atLocation:point inView:nil];
}
```

With storyboard in a ViewController obviously I changed `self.window` whit:

```
[[NSApplication sharedApplication].windows objectAtIndex:0]
or
[[NSApplication sharedApplication] mainWindow]
```

but doesn't seem right choices. Is it possible that with storyboard this is no longer possible? This sounds bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the parent window of a view controller in a storyboard with

```
self.view.window;
```

Comment: Thanks! And also `@property (strong) IBOutlet` not `(weak)`